# Multiple GSM Dongles

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem

I'm using wvdial to connect two 3g dongles. I put the dongles on my PC and both are recognized and setup correctly.

I've used first one or second one separated having success, but if I try to connect both, strange thing happen. When I connect the second interface, the first are disconnected and all USB devices are bloqued, inclusive the keyboard and mouse. Apparently the OS restarts all USB devices... I can't understand if this is true and for what reason it's occurs...

Please, If someone can help me, I really appreciate... I can send logs, version, etc, but I don't know at this moment what information is relevant to get the diagnostics.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but are both from the same Manufacturer? check the prod ID etc via lsusb. If two usb dev have same ID then that might mess up the mounting system tree. Instead of two dongles use one via tethering to a portable device. This will express in Linux as "usb0" so it might work that way.

Also, what you are trying to do, which I also would like to achieve, is called "bonding" see wikipedia page here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation.

Problem with dongles per se is that they use PPP as the protocol which is verrry goofy in that the link can "go down" w/o warning or detection and come up again (cell phone companies). This is very difficult to bypass using the bond protocols which assume at the least a steady link.

Nonetheless, there's a co called teradek (http://www.dvc.uk.com/acatalog/BOND.html)  in UK which sells a GBP2,000 (!) "box" which allows you to connect multiple dongles to stream live video out of Syria for example! Yes, i know, too expensive unless some news channel handles your expenses.

Pls  update me someone if htis can be done in s/w on my Tux box?

EDIT:
Actually I came to this below solution backwards: There is a company called "Connectify" and they sell s/w for $100 for windoze which has prob reverse engineered a standard linux solution of "bonding" module in the kernel!! they claim in their advertising how "hard" it is in linux: ie. load kernel module enable script etc.

so reverse engineering connectify's statement I stumbled on following procedure
install ifenslave:
sudo apt-get install ifenslave

then 
modprobe bonding

ifconfig bond0 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0

ifenslave bond0 eth0 ppp0 usb0

ifconfig bond0 up

in addition to implementing straight "bonding" above, you can install a local reverse proxy like HAProxy, so apparently there are MANY MANY ways to do Link Aggregation in Linux only we have to learn about it.

Comment: Hi, I did the bond configuration and I guess is working. How can I prove it? I'm using iptraf, but I don't know if is the correct way to prove if bound is working...

Comment: I configured for routing.